# Is there any way to change the height of the leftCalloutAccessoryView for a MKAnnotationView?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

I want to display more than 2 lines of data in a callout.  I now know that both the annotation title and subtitles are limited to 1 line each.

Reading the following Apple documentation implies if you subclass MKAnnotationView and override leftCalloutAccessoryView you can create a custom callout view.  This works but it seems like the height of the callout is fixed to some value.  For example no matter how big I make `height` the height of the call out is limited.

Am I missing something here?  If not what is a good alternative way to display some addition info?  I know about the rightCalloutAccessory, but I would rather not have to hit the annotation and then hit the accessory just to get a couple more lines of info.

```
import UIKit

class MyMKAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

  override var leftCalloutAccessoryView: UIView! {
    get {
      let height: CGFloat = 100.0
      return UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,height))
    }
    set {

    }
  }
}
```

> Subclassing Notes You can use the MKAnnotationView class as is or
>   subclass it to provide custom behavior as needed. The image property
>   of the class lets you set the appearance of the annotation view
>   without subclassing directly. You might also create custom subclasses
>   as a convenience and use them to put the annotation view in a known
>   state. For example, the MKPinAnnotationView subclass initializes the
>   contents of the annotation view to a pin image.
>
> There are no special requirements for subclassing MKAnnotationView.
>   However, the following list includes some reasons you might want to
>   subclass and some of the methods you would override to implement the
>   desired behavior:
>
> To put the annotation view into a consistent state, provide a custom
>   initialization method. Your custom initialization method would then
>   call initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier: to initialize the superclass.
>
> To provide custom callout views, override the leftCalloutAccessoryView
>   method and use it to return the views.
>
> If you support draggable annotation views in iOS 4.0 and later, your
>   subclass is responsible for changing the value in the dragState
>   property to appropriate values at key transition points in the drag
>   operation. For more information, see the description of that property.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: No I did not.  I ended up with a custom view a a fixed location.  Not ideal but worked for what I wanted to show